# How to make sure a maven dependency is in a given scope?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

In a project I'm working on, we discovered Oracle coherence product was used by our EAR as a `compile` dependency. This triggered weird classpath issues that have been detected and coherence is now a `provided` dependency.

However, I would like to make sure nobody ever do again the mistake of using, directly or not, coherence as a `compile`. So, is there any maven plugin/solution which, given a set of dependency constraints, will make sure all maven modules enforce these constraints ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a deep look at the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) which supports exactly such things.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>com.xyz:abc:*:jar:compile</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.xyz:abc:*:jar:runtime</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.xyz:abc:*:jar:test</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```